# Plone caching with nginx

Tags: nginx, plone

Is there a good way to set "expires"-Header with Nginx, for contents out from Plone (without file-endings!!)

Because:

- "If" is evil (http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil)
- and :

  if ($request_uri ~* ".(htm|html)$") { expires 1d; }

is not working...

Her are my conf-Files:

- domain - http://pastebin.com/5qSEnXHk
- caching - http://pastebin.com/Z3jKBBBj

Comment: Why Nginx? This is what plone.app.caching and the caching control panel is for.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx respects cache headers set by the upstream server.

Plone has its internal mechanism, called [plone.app.caching](http://docs.plone.org/manage/deploying/testing_tuning/performance/index.html) which you can use to set caching of different HTTP responses on Plone's level

- Caching of different content types
- Caching of static resources

... and such

`plone.app.caching` has been bundled in Plone since version 4.2.